# GridControl display values in new line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, syncfusion, gridcontrol

I have a  class wherein I am storing all the values of `FileALine` and `FileBLine` properties into a list called `Changes`
The code for the properties is as shown below.

```
public class Result
{
    public Result()
    {
        this.Changes = new List<Difference>();
    }

    public IList<Difference> Changes { get; set; }
}

public class Differences
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }

    public string FileALine { get; set; }

    public string FileBLine { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling the `Changes` list from a form to populate a Synfusion GridControl. It has two Columns `DataRow` and `Details`. Right now I am only able to fill in either `FileAline` values or `FileBLine` values into the second column.

I am unable to figure out how to display both `FileAline` values on one line and `FileBLine` values in the next line as shown in the image below.

```
public partial class Form: Form
{
    private void DisplayValues(Result result)
    {
        if (result != null && result.Changes.Count > 0)
        {
            var differences = result.Changes;
            this.detailsGridControl.RowCount = differences.Count;
            this.detailsGridControl.ColCount = 2;

            for (var i = 0; i < differences.Count; i++)
            {
                var detailsA = differences[i];
                var row = i + 1;
                this.detailsGridControl[row, (int)FormColumns.DataRow].Text = detailsA.LineNumber.ToString();
                this.detailsGridControl[row, (int)FormColumns.Details].Text = detailsA.FileALine;
                this.detailsGridControl[row, (int)FormColumns.Details].Text = detailsA.FileBLine;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the output must be something like this.

[image: Output]

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below suggestions.

Suggestion 1

In the DisplayValues() method of Form, you are trying to set the FileALine and FileBLine for the same cell. So, the CellValue will be overridden and returns only FileBLine only. In order to set the CellValue from list, the PopulateValues() method can be used. Refer to the below code and sample,

```
Dim difference As New List(Of Differences)()
difference.Add(New Differences() With {.LineNumber = 1, .FileALine = `"FileLineA", .FileBLine = "FileLineB"})
difference.Add(New Differences() With {.LineNumber = 2, .FileALine = "FileLineB", .FileBLine = "FileLineA"})
Dim r As New Result()
For Each d As Differences In difference
r.Changes.Add(New Data() With {.DataRow = d.LineNumber, .Details = d.FileALine})
r.Changes.Add(New Data() With {.DataRow = d.LineNumber, .Details = d.FileBLine})
Next d
Me.gridControl1.PopulateHeaders(GridRangeInfo.Cells(0, 1, gridControl1.RowCount, gridControl1.ColCount), r.Changes)
Me.gridControl1.PopulateValues(GridRangeInfo.Cells(1, 1, gridControl1.RowCount, gridControl1.ColCount), r.Changes)
Me.gridControl1.Refresh()
```

Suggestion 2

You can also set the CellValue by Text property of GridStyleInfo class. refer to the sample,

```
Dim difference As New List(Of Differences)()
difference.Add(New Differences() With {.LineNumber = 1, .FileALine = "FileLineA", .FileBLine = "FileLineB"})
difference.Add(New Differences() With {.LineNumber = 2, .FileALine = "FileLineB", .FileBLine = "FileLineA"})
Dim r As New Result()
For Each d As Differences In difference
r.Changes.Add(New Data() With {.DataRow = d.LineNumber, .Details = d.FileALine})
 r.Changes.Add(New Data() With {.DataRow = d.LineNumber, .Details = d.FileBLine})
Next d
DisplayValues(r)
Private Sub DisplayValues(ByVal result As Result)
If result IsNot Nothing AndAlso result.Changes.Count > 0 Then
   Dim differences = result.Changes
   Me.gridControl1.RowCount = result.Changes.Count
   Me.gridControl1.ColCount = 2
   For i = 0 To differences.Count - 1
      Dim detailsA = TryCast(differences(i), Data)
      Dim row = i + 1
      Me.gridControl1(row, 1).Text = detailsA.DataRow.ToString()
     'To set FileALine or FileBLine for column 2
      Me.gridControl1(row, 2).Text = detailsA.Details
      Next i
   End If
End Sub
```

Note: you can create an object for the list to populate data as your convenient.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, will try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually figured out the solution.

```
for (var i = 0; i < differences.Count; i++)
{
     var detailsA = differences[i];
     var row = i + 1;
     this.detailsGridControl[row, (int)FormColumns.DataRow].Text = detailsA.LineNumber.ToString();
     this.detailsGridControl[row, (int)FormColumns.Details].Text = detailsA.FileALine + Environment.NewLine + detailsA.FileBLine;
}
```